# OpenGL Picking selects on wrong places

Tags: c++, opengl, picking

I'm trying to recognize a drawn object on a mousPressEvent in OpenGL in Qt with picking.

I did some research but wasn't able to find the problem.

Clearly  it recognizes something (because the return value of glRenderMode(GL_RENDER) is often an integer > 0), but not necessarily when I click on an object.

I think gluPerspective is the problem right here, but i just don't know how to resolve it.

mousePressEvent:

```
void WorldView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
       GLuint buff[256];
       GLint hits;
       GLint view[4];

       //Buffer to store selection data
       glSelectBuffer(256, buff);

       //Viewport information
       glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, view);

       //Switch to select mode
       glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);

       //Clear the name stack!
       glInitNames();

       //Restric viewing volume
       glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
       glPushMatrix();
       glLoadIdentity();

       //Restrict draw area
       gluPickMatrix(e->x(), e->y(), 1.0, 1.0, view);
       gluPerspective(40.0f, (GLfloat)view[2]/(GLfloat)view[3], 1.0, 100.0);

       //Draw the objects onto the screen
       glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

       //Draw only the names in the stack
        paintGL();

       //Back into projection mode to push the matrix
       glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
       glPopMatrix();

       hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);//number of recognized objects

       printf("\n%d\n",hits);

       //Back to modelview mode
       glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}
```

Draw function:

```
void WorldView::paintGL ()
{
    this->dayOfYear = (this->dayOfYear+1);
    this->hourOfDay = (this->hourOfDay+1) % 24;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();

    // store current matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glPushMatrix( );

    gluLookAt(camPosx ,camPosy ,camPosz,
        camViewx,camViewy,camViewz,
        camUpx, camUpy, camUpz );

    //Draw Axes
    glDisable( GL_LIGHTING );
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(10.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 10.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 10.0);
    glEnd();

    //Draw objects we want to pick
    glPushName(0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3d(1,1,1);
        glVertex3d(2,3,2);
        glVertex3d(5,2,2);
    glEnd();
    glPopName();
     glPushName(1);
     glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
         glVertex3d(7,-5,1);
         glVertex3d(10,3,2);
         glVertex3d(10,2,2);
     glEnd();
     glPopName();
     glPushName(2);
      glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
          glVertex3d(1,-5,7);
          glVertex3d(2,3,9);
          glVertex3d(5,2,9);
      glEnd();
      glPopName();
}
```

EDIT1: Maybe completing the code could help?

Initializer:

```
void WorldView::initializeGL ()
{

    this->dayOfYear = 0;
    this->hourOfDay = 0;

    // Initialize QGLWidget (parent)
    QGLWidget::initializeGL();

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    // Black canvas
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

    // Place light
    glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );
    glEnable( GL_LIGHT0 );
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    GLfloat light0_position [] = {0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f};
    GLfloat light_diffuse []={ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    glLightfv ( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light0_position );
    glLightfv ( GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse );
}
```

resizer:

```
void WorldView::resizeGL ( int width, int height )
{
    if ((width<=0) || (height<=0))
        return;

    //set viewport
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();

    //set persepective
    //change the next line order to have a different perspective
    GLdouble aspect_ratio=(GLdouble)width/(GLdouble)height;
    gluPerspective(40.0f, aspect_ratio, 1.0, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Comment: There is nothing special about using the namestack for this. You could accomplish the same thing portably (across versions of GL and even between different APIs) if you implemented color picking instead. In fact, behind the scenes that is effectively how this winds up being implemented by drivers that still support that legacy part of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Use bullet raycast and not gl_Select which is way too slow and unwieldy. This will also make you get away from calling paintGL manually and other glCalls...in qt mousepressevent. **Dont do this!**